# Registering servlet in Jetty in OSGi environment (Class loading problems)

Tags: servlets, jetty, osgi

I have an OSGi application with embedded Jetty 8.1.1 server.

When I run my application as a monolit (no OSGi environment) I can successfuly register servlets by calling `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.addServlet(String className, String mapping)` method. So now I'm trying to do the same in OSGi environment.

The goal is to write a bundle (`servlet-extender`) which would register servlets provided by other bundles when they are started (extender pattern). Therefore after my application starts there are (among others) only two essential bundles running: `jetty` and `servlet-extender`.

**1st attempt to write `servlet-extender`:**

First I decided to declare servlets with their mappings in `MANIFEST.MF` file of a bundle providing servlets. If such bundle is started then `servlet-extender` searches its `MANIFEST.MF` for servlet mapping declarations. If any servlet mapping declaration was found then `servlet-extender` called aforementioned `ServletContextHandler.addServlet(...)` method to actually register the servlet.

While the idea seemed OK there is a problem with class loading. In fact Jetty calls `Class.forName("org.my.servlets.MyServletClass").newInstance()`. While `jetty` bundle does not import `org.my.servlets` package the call `Class.forName("org.my.servlets.MyServletClass")` fails with `ClassNotFoundException`.

**2nd attempt to write `servlet-extender`:**

I searched for some articles related to class loading in OSGi. [This one](http://njbartlett.name/2010/08/30/osgi-readiness-loading-classes.html) gave me a hope that I can resolve the previous problem by providing loaded servlet classes through some OSGi service. So I created `ServletProvider` service with `Map<Class<? extends Servlet>, String> getServlets()` method (the method just returns servlet classes mapped to some context). Then I modified `servlet-extender` so that it does not search for servlet mappings in `MANIFEST.MF`. It now rather wait until some bundle registers `ServletProvider` implementation. If such service is registered in OSGi service registry then `servlet-extender` calls its `getServlets()` method and tries to register returned servlet classes in `jetty`. While `jetty` now does not need to call `Class.forName("org.my.servlets.MyServletClass")` it still have to call `servletClass.newInstance()` to instantiate servlet. And unfortunatelly it still fails with `ClassNotFoundException`.

I understand that this can be resolved if `jetty` bundle would import `org.my.servlets` package. But this is not possible while `jetty` bundle is provided by 3rd party and I cannot modify its `Import-Package` declaration.

**How to dynamically register servlets provided by arbitrary bundles?**

P.S.: I can't use "OSGi Http Service" because I have to use Jetty's 8.1.1 WebSocketServlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: I am still curious about the way of registering servlets declaratively: through servlet class name. Is it possible?

A: Yes :)

First possible solution: if you are allowed to modify the jetty manifest, you could add "DynamicImport-Package: *" to the manifest, this will allow it to load any classes while at the same time it won't be depending on custom org.my.servlets packages.
Of course, note that this is bad practice in general for OSGi.

Second possible solution: 
jetty remains like it is.
Servlet bundles list containing servlets declaratively in the manifest, as in your first attempt. 
The key here is the servlet extender. It will create the servlet and register it in jetty. **The important thing about this whole classloading problem is that the creation of the servlet object has to be done somewhere where the classloader (in this case the classloader of the servlet extender) has access to the classes of the servlets.** 
This cannot happen in jetty, because you cannot modify the MF. 
However, you have full control over the MF of servlet extender, right?

You can either import org.my.servlets (not recommended, since it cannot be foreseen what servlets have to be installed in the future);

or use "DynamicImport-Package: *" in the MF (not recommended practice in general ;) )

or (recommended) the extender loads the classes from the servlet jar using the classloader of the servlet jar - using **Bundle loadClass()** method (see [org.osgi.framework.Bundle](http://dz.prosyst.com/pdoc/mBS_SDK/um/runtime/osgi/docs/framework/api/framework/index.html)). This will load the class correctly. Note that this could be subject to security restrictions.

Comment: The last solution you proposed (`Bundle.loadClass()`) works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to do this yourself. There is already pax-web which provides exactly this functionality. See http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxweb/Pax+Web

Pax web is also available in Apache Karaf. There you can install it with feature:install http-whiteboard.

If you want to do it yourself you can look at the code of pax web. There the concept is to  simply register you servlets as OSGi services. With service properties you can supply parameters like the http path to register.

Comment: Pax web is: "OSGi R4 Http Service and Web Applications (OSGi Enterprise Release chapter 128) implementation using Jetty 7." Last sentence in my post should explain why I can't use Pax web.

Comment: I think the newest pax web supports Jetty 8 not sure about the WebSocketServlet though. Btw. ops4j is very open for help. Perhaps you can add the features you need to pax web.

Answer (score 0):

I recently noticed that Jetty's 8.1.1 `ServletContextHandler` has a method `addServlet(ServletHolder, String)`. I modified aforementioned `servlet-extender` so it now registers servlets in the following way:

```
 public void servletProviderRegistered(ServletProvider servletProvider) {
     Map<? extends HttpServlet, String> servlets = servletProvider.getServlets();
     for (Entry<? extends HttpServlet, String> entry : servlets.entrySet()) {
         HttpServlet servletInstance = entry.getKey();
         String mapping mapping = entry.getValue();
         ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(servletInstance);
         servletContextHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, mapping);
     }
 }
```

Using this approach Jetty doesn't need to call `Class.forName("org.my.servlets.MyServletClass").newInstance()` so now I don't get `ClassNotFoundException`.

Since this is a solution to my problem **I am still curious about the way of registering servlets declaratively: through servlet class name**. **Is it possible?**

Comment: Using the class name is normally a bad choice in OSGi as a class name is only unique relative to a bundle classloader. It is better to create the Servlet Class in your own bundle and register it as a service. If you use blueprint or DS for this then I would also call this declarative.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I was a bit stuck. Now I think I get it. OSGi world is very different from 'not-modular' Java world.